# How to enable specific input with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of 10 input with disabled property like this

```
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" class="rule-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="First Rule" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="10" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="rule-btn" data-id="1" data-poin="10">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="Second Rule" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="20" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="rule-btn" data-id="2" data-poin="20">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click Edit button, I want to remove disabled property and alert class for input which is same row with that button. I have tried like this

```
$('form.rule-form').find('button.rule-btn').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){

        $(this).text('Submit');

        $('form.rule-form').find('input[name="rule"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-info');
        });

        $('form.rule-form').find('input[name="point"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-success');
        });

        $(this).click(function(){
            $('form.rule-form').submit();
        })
    });
});
```

but it seems all of input list are enabled after I click Edit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you need to use DOM traversal to find the `input` elements relevant to the row of the clicked button. To do that you can use a combination of `closest()` and `find()`.

Also note that a simpler way to submit the form on the second click of the button would be to change the type to `submit` in the HTML, then use `preventDefault()` on the first click to stop the submission. Try this:

```js
$('form.rule-form button.rule-btn').click(function(e) {
  var $btn = $(this);
  if ($btn.text() !== 'Submit') {
    e.preventDefault();
    $btn.text('Submit');
    $btn.closest('.form-row').find('input')
      .prop('disabled', false)
      .removeClass('alert-info alert-success');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" class="rule-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
      <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="First Rule" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="10" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <button type="submit" class="rule-btn" data-id="1" data-poin="10">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
      <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="Second Rule" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="20" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <button type="submit" class="rule-btn" data-id="2" data-poin="20">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works. What is the different between parent() and closest(), it seem closest is very common to use rather than parent()

Comment: The difference is that `parent()` looks for the single parent element, whereas `closest()` looks all the way up the DOM tree to find the selector your provide. You can read more in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/parent & http://api.jquery.com/closest

Comment: how to get it back disabled if I click outside input or somewhere else? Should I make another button to cancel it?

Comment: That would be the easiest way. Alternatively you can detect a click outside the button or the inputs and cancel then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can't find your element under `$(this)`, so navigating up the DOM hierarchy will help:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="rule"]').prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-info');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="point"]').prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-success');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this find input and enable on clikcing edit button if once edit is clicked button text will be changed into submit on next click it check whether button text is submit or not if it is submit it will submit the form.

```js
$(function() {$('.rule-btn').click(function(){
if(alreadyClicked)
  {
    
  $(this).attr('type','submit');
   return;
  }
$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="rule"]').prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-info');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="point"]').prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-success');
   $(this).attr('id','submit');
   $(this).text("submit");
   alreadyClicked = true;
   console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
var alreadyClicked = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" class="rule-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="First Rule" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="10" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="rule-btn" data-id="1" data-poin="10">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="rule" class="form-control alert-info" value="Second Rule" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control alert-success" value="20" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="rule-btn" data-id="2" data-poin="20">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by finding the siblings and change attribute value.

```js
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".form-group").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Same way you can remove class also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rule-btn').click(function(){
   $('input[name="rule"]', $(this).closest('.form-row')).each(function(){
     $(this).prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-info');
 })
 $('input[name="point"]', $(this).closest('.form-row')).each(function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', false).toggleClass('alert-success');
  })
})
```

You can do simply like pass parent and find element and you can do whatever with element